# onclick() not updating slider text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bootstrap-4

I have a map with a slider that controls the display of some points as you move the slider left and right (from year 1 to year 10).

I have some of these points filtered based on another parameter that is tied to 4 individual buttons.

When I slide the slider, and then click on one of the buttons, the text that tells you how many points are on the map doesnt update. It only updates after you move the slider (again, not when you click the button).

I want to ensure that as soon as one clicks the button, not only does the map update, but the text also updates.

Ive tried a variety of options, but none seem to work. I am not entirely sure where to look here.

The easiest way to see the issue is by following the link, i have everything hosted on bl.ocks.

https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/Ov8dHR7jI09aTFSU
(the plnkr needs to be refreshed for the data to start loading)

no error messages

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added a plnkr that reproduces the code, deleted as much extraneous stuff that i could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty and easy fix is to just replace `filterData()` call inside the `buttonClick` with what you do in slider callback -- `document.getElementById("slidertext").innerHTML = "Achieved Goals:  " + filterData() + "   ";`, really confusing you didn't come up with it. Probably should be refactored into a separate method to avoid repetition.